# Loading Travis-CI cache takes as long as fresh install of all dependencies (using yarn)

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, yarnpkg, continuous-delivery

**Loading *node_modules* from build cache in TravisCI takes as much time as installing all the dependencies from the scratch with yarn command.**

While trying to speed up our TravisCI build, we've wanted to cache node_modules and yarn so builds in our open PRs triggered by new commits don't have to always install all dependencies again.

The problem is that loading cached node_modules takes as much time as installing everything fresh new with yarn command. Is this expected behavior or are we using incorrectly written `travis.yml`?

Here is cache part our `travis.yml`:

```
cache: 
  yarn: true
  directories:
    - node_modules
    - ~/.cache    #this one caches Cypress binary which is saved at '/home/travis/.cache/Cypress' (more info here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Caching)
```

I certainly hoped that using cache would save us some time. But **loading cache takes 49 seconds vs. running yarn takes 51**. Not a huge performance boost.

[image: Picture of loading cache benchmark]
[image: Picture of installing dependencies with yarn benchmark]

Comment: Per the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#things-not-to-cache): "*Large files that are quick to install but slow to download do not benefit from caching*".  Basically the Travis cache is an S3 bucket, so restoring from cache still involves network transfer time.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks! It might indeed be the reasom. But the doc also says: "everything related to tools like npm is what should go into the cache" Node_modules definitely are as related to npm as it gets. Anyway, we're running yarn on every build now :/